# How to structure d3 v4 plugin for the visualization of hierarchical datasets?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plugins, tree, hierarchical-data

Looking for advice on **how to best structure `d3` `v4` plugin for the visualization of hierarchical data-sets**, currently working on.

Want to visualize a network consisting of several subnets. The subnet `nodes` and `edges` are displayed in a `tree structure` and their positions are arranged by an algorithm (see left side of the example). Each subnet is then placed by another algorithm in a way to prevent overlapping (see right side of the example). The following link shows an abstract example.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBvnJ.png)

The goal is to develop a `d3` plugin that visualizes all subnets and displays them in a complete connected network. An early prototype in JavaScript already exists and need to transfer the two parts (the algorithm for positioning the `nodes / links` of the subnets and  the placement of the subnets in a certain areas) into a `d3` plugin.

One idea to visualize the subnets is to modify the `d3` tree layout module by replacing the algorithm to position the nodes and links. Not sure whether it's better to develop two `d3` plugins for the two layers, which together build the visualization or to do this in one single `d3` plugin.

Does anyone have experience developing `d3` plugins on several layers and can help? How could a possible architecture for such a `d3` plugin look like?